# ffmpeg capture frame from input on demand

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to capture image frames from a webcam on demand. I'm using ffmpeg and I was thinking of keeping a stream running, sort of as a daemon, with:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 /dev/null
```

Is it possible, and how would I go about capturing an image from that stream on demand?

I need the capture to be as quick as possible.

To add a little bit of context, my project is using a Raspberry Pi to control multiple servos. I want to be able to send back image stills from 2 cameras along with servo position data, so they're in sync. This would hopefully be up to 5fps? Am I dreaming, or should something like this be possible?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "on demand"? Why not simply run `ffmpeg` whenever you want to capture an image from the v4l2 input device?

Comment: I figured having to initialise ffmpeg and open the camera to take an image would be a lengthy process, and that maybe it'd be possible to already have the stream running, and capture from it.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard ffmpeg takes too long to take a picture. I'm aiming for something like 5 fps. That's why i thought maybe there was a way to have the camera running and grab frames from it when needed

Comment: The Raspberry Pi may just be too underpowered, but I don't know. You may be able to come up with a custom solution using the FFmpeg libraries, but I have no experience with that. Or perhaps you can continuously output frames and keep keep the ones you want. Maybe the RPi camera module will perform better than a typical webcam using v4l2, but I know little of that or the RPi. Not very helpful...